# Delete directories after compressing with tar

Tags: linux, find, tar

I´m trying to compress a whole directory tree, leaving just one .tar.bz2 file instead of each directory that I found with find. The purpose is to create a cronjob for doing this in weekly basis.

The command that I´m succesfully using to list the directories that I want to compress is:

```
find rootDirectory/ -mindepth 2  -type d  -not -name '*.bz2'
```

And the one that I´m using to compress and do the whole job is:

```
find rootDirectory/ -mindepth 2  -type d  -not -name '*.bz2' -exec  tar --remove-files -cjf ./{}.tar.bz2 ./{}  \ ;
```

It´s doing the job OK, but it´s throwing an error for each compressed directory, like this:

```
find: ‘rootDirectory/directory2/02-09-2020-183833-700’: No such file or directory
```

I got the desired result in rootDirectory/directory2/02-09-2020-183833-700.tar.bz2 , but I want to get rid of the error on execution time. What am I doing wrong?.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `--remove-files` makes `tar` remove the source directory after creating the archive. The `find` utility does not know that the directory disappears and will still try to enter it to find other things matching its search criteria.

To avoid entering the directories that you create archives of in this way, add `--prune` at the end of the `find` command:

```
find rootDirectory/ -mindepth 2  -type d  ! -name '*.bz2' \
    -exec  tar --remove-files -cjf {}.tar.bz2 {}  \; --prune
```

The `--prune` primary tells `find` to remove that search path from the paths to investigate, so that it won't try to enter that directory (which no longer exists).

It strikes me that you probably don't need `find` in this case, since you will create `tar` archives of all directories two levels down from `rootDirectory`.  It would be easily done with a loop:

```bsh
for dir in rootDirectory/*/*/; do
    tar --remove-files -cj -f "${dir%/}.tar.bz2" "$dir"
done
```

The only difference here is that you would miss directories having hidden names.